# Differential and common mode MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, differential-amplifier, small-signal

I am studying this problem and its solution:

[image]

There are some concepts I don't understand:

1. How did the output voltage when vi = 20mv become this?

[image]

I already got ADD and Vo, I just don't understand how that became the solution.

2. For letter b, how did the input range for the given amplifer became this equation?

[image]

Where did 2 from vi/2 go?